# JSDoc green highlighting in Webstorm

Tags: webstorm, jsdoc

What does the highlighted green mean in my JSDoc?

[image]

My JSDoc seems legit. But what is the IDE trying to say to me with the green?

Comment: It's a Language Injection .. most likely HTML flavour. But it should not be injected there (in that place) -- must be a bug.

Comment: [WEB-1523](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-1523)